# XElement.Value is stripping XML tags from content

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xml-parsing, xelement

I have the following XML:

```
<Message>
    <Identification>c387e36a-0d79-405a-745c-7fc3e1aa8160</Identification>
    <SerializedContent>
        {"Identification":"81d090ca-b913-4f15-854d-059055cc49ff","LogType":0,"LogContent":"{\"EntitiesChanges\":\"
        <audit>
            <username>acfc</username>
            <date>2015-06-04T15:15:34.7979485-03:00</date>
            <entities>
                <entity>
                    <properties>
                        <property>
                            <name>DepId</name>
                            <current>2</current>
                        </property>
                        <property>
                            <name>FirstName</name>
                            <current>camila</current>
                        </property>
                    </properties>
                </entity>
            </entities>
        </audit>\",\"FeatureName\":\"Adicionar Cliente\",\"Operations\":0,\"MachineNameOrigin\":\"VERDE\"}"}
    </SerializedContent>
</Message>
```

and this code:

```
[HttpPost]
[ActionName("Message")]
public HttpResponseMessage MessageListener()
{
    var requestString = Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

    try
    {
        var xdoc = XDocument.Parse(requestString);

        var xSerializedContent = xdoc.Root.Element("SerializedContent");    

        var serializedContent = xSerializedContent.Value;

    }
    catch (XmlException e)
    {
        return CreateHttpResponseMessage("Invalid XML. " + e.Message);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return CreateHttpResponseMessage(e.Message);
    }
}
```

The `serializedContent` from `xSerializedContent.Value` is this:

```
{  
    "Identification":"81d090ca-b913-4f15-854d-059055cc49ff",
    "LogType":0,
    "LogContent":"{\"EntitiesChanges\":\"acfc2015-06-04T15:15:34.7979485-03:00DepId2FirstNamecamila\",\"FeatureName\":\"Adicionar Cliente\",\"Operations\":0,\"MachineNameOrigin\":\"VERDE\"}"
}
```

As we can see the `<SerializedContent>` is a JSON and inside the JSON I have another XML inside `EntitiesChanges`. **How to avoid the XML tags remotion from the** `<SerializedContent>`?

Expected result:

```
{  
    "Identification":"81d090ca-b913-4f15-854d-059055cc49ff",
    "LogType":0,
    "LogContent":"{\"EntitiesChanges\":\"<audit><username>acfc</username><date>2015-06-04T15:15:34.7979485-03:00</date><entities><entity><properties><property><name>DepId</name><current>2</current></property><property><name>FirstName</name><current>camila</current></property></properties></entity></entities></audit>\",\"FeatureName\":\"Adicionar Cliente\",\"Operations\":0,\"MachineNameOrigin\":\"VERDE\"}"
}
```

Comment: Use CDATA in your XML ?

Comment: Indeed - aside from anything else, this is a *really* horrible format. It's unclear whether the nested XML elements are intended to be XML, or part of the text nodes. The `Value` property is doing exactly what it's meant to - it's concatenating the descendant text nodes.

Comment: @bas, my system receives that xml from a third party and unfortunately, for now at least, I can't change the format.

Comment: @JonSkeet, my system receives that xml from a third party and unfortunately, for now at least, I can't change the format (and I agree, really horrible).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As others have said, this format is truly horrible, and will break as soon as the XML embedded in the JSON will contain double quotes (because in the JSON they will be encoded as `\"`, which will make the XML invalid). The JSON should really be embedded as CDATA.

Now, assuming that you have no control over the format, you need to read the "inner XML" of the `<SerializedContent>` element. There is no support for this out of the box, but you can easily create an extension method that does it:

```
static class XmlExtensions
{
    public static string GetInnerXml(this XNode node)
    {
        using (var reader = node.CreateReader())
        {
            reader.MoveToContent();
            return reader.ReadInnerXml();
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can use `.GetInnerXml()` instead of `.Value`, and it will give you the expected result.

Comment: Worked! Many thanks. In addition I've contacted the team responsible for the XML asking for enclose the SerializedContent into CDATA.

Answer (score 1):

You're using the `Value` property, which is documented to return the concatenated *text* descendant nodes within the element.

So it sounds like you want a concatenation of the string representations of all the child nodes. So you could use:

```
var serializedContent = string.Join("", xSerializedContent.Nodes);
```

I *think* that should do what you want, although as noted in the question comments, it's pretty horrible.

Comment: Thank you very much! Your solution worked. I chose other answer just because the output looks better without \r\n (so I don't have to get rid of this). Thanks!